# File erased in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a weird one.
I was working on a project in Eclipse (with CDT) when my computer went blue-screen. I remember saving all the files quite recently before that. The computer rebooted with no problems, but when I opened Eclipse again, the file that I was editing at the time was empty (not deleted, so I can't Restore from Local History). All the other files were intact. What happened, is this a problem with Eclipse or my computer, and how can I retrieve the file?

EDIT: I viewed the file using vim on Cygwin and actually it wasn't empty, it was full of unprintable ^@ characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking local history in eclipse didn't actually show anything, but I did solve it another way. What I did is I went to `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history` as suggested [here](https://javabyu.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/java-file-corrupted-in-eclipse-how-to-restore-the-content/), and sorted the entries by last modified. I scrolled down to the latest entry before the crash, then opened the files inside it one by one until I found the file that was erased.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file and choose 'Replace with > Local History...'. This will show you the last few versions of the file that Eclipse has saved.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't show anything. Fortunately, I figured out how to do it another way.